# how to download file inside vscode terminal from remote server?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want something like

```
code --download_file [path_to_file]
```

to download file from remote server to my local computer (instead of manual select file in file explorer because sometimes the file is not in currently open project)

Answer (score 3):

Try `python3 -m http.server -d $(THE_DIRECTORY_PATH_TO_FILE)`, and vscode will simply forward port 8000 locally. Visual Studio Code for the Web also works well. (i'm using a vscode-web for learning and meet the same question, finally solving by initing the simple file-sharing server).